# Super keyword in java and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, super

I am a newbie to the world of Java.
While studying Multithreading I came across this program :-

```
class Shared 
{
 int x;
 synchronized void show(String s,int a)
{
  x=a;
  System.out.println("Starting in method" +s+  " " +x);
  try 
  {
     Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("Ending from method" +s+ " " +x);   
  }   
 }
}
class CustomThread extends Thread
{
  Shared s;
  public CustomThread(Shared s,String str)
{
 super (str);
  this.s=s;
  start();
}
 public void run()
{
 s.show(Thread.currentThread().getName(),10 );
}
}  

class CustomThread1 extends Thread
 {
    Shared s;
    public CustomThread1(Shared s,String str)
  {
     super (str);
  this.s=s;
  start();
}
   public void run()
  {
   s.show(Thread.currentThread().getName(),20);
  }
}   
class RunSyn
{
   public static void main(String...s)
   {
      Shared st=new Shared();
      CustomThread t1=new CustomThread(st,"one");
      CustomThread1 t2=new CustomThread1(st,"two");

       }
    }
```

What does the line
***super(str)***;
does in this context?
As far as i understand it calls the constructor ***Thread (String name)*** of the **Thread**
class. That in turn creates a new Thread object.
But in the output it is seen that the String passed in the constructor of ***CustomThread*** and ***CustomThread1*** is being passed in the ***void show (String s,int a)*** of ***Shared*** class?
Please explain what is happening actually?
Thanks!!

Comment: `super(...)` is context independent. It always serves the same purpose, calling the super constructor with whatever arguments you pass to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `super(String)` statement is an explicit super class constructor call.

All java constructors must call one or another constructor from their super classes. By default the no-args constructor is invoked, but in this way you can explicitly specify which super class constructor to invoke.

The [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class constructor that takes a `String` argument creates a `Thread` with a specific name (as opposed to automatically generated names such as Thread-1).

The easiest way for you to determine what the complete program does is to actually execute it.

When the [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) method of a `Thread` instance is called the thread begins to execute (the [`run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) method eventually gets called). As you can see, in this case, the `run()` method of `CustomThread1` class simply calls the `show(String, int)` method of its `Shared` instance, which prints whatever it is passed into the console.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the `super(str)` method calls the constructor for [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.String%29). This overrides the default functionality which is to inject a `super()` call at the beginning of your constructor.

As for what it *does*, the string passed to Thread will give the thread a name. This will allow you to easily identify the thread in debugging sessions and in Thread dumps. Without the string, it will have a boring name like, "Thread-5".

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor calls two methods: `super(str)` and `start()`.
The first method is the constructor of the superclass, so `Thread(String)` which creates a new Thread object with the given string as name.

The second method, `start()`, actually creates and starts a new thread. In this new thread, the `run()` method is called (similar to `main()` of the entire program, but for a thread). This method then calls `s.show(Thread.currentThread().getName(),10);`. Since you set the thread name to the given string `str`, `Thread.currentThread().getName()` returns that same string.